# Require a custom header on a get request for an s3 object in bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to require a custom header like

`"x-amz-meta-blah:foobar"`

when making a GET request for an s3 object as part of your bucket policy?

Something like;

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
   {
     "Sid":"111",
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Principal":{
      "AWS":"123456789"
     },
     "Action":"s3:GetObject",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bucket01/*"
   },
   {
     "Sid":"112",
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Principal":{
      "AWS":"123456789"
     },
     "Action":"s3:GetObject",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bucket01/*",
     "Condition":{
      "StringEquals":{
        "s3:x-amz-meta-blah":[
         "x-amz-meta-blah:foobar"
        ]
      }
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't find anything in the documentation to indicate that there is support for `s3:x-amz-meta-*`-related condition keys in policy statements.  Do you see that somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

According to [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp), it seems possible:

[image]

Comment: Your test doesn't actually prove anything.  It appears to be an `Allow` test against a `StringNotEqual` condition, but you're making the string be equal and it's still allowed.  To prove whether a policy works as intended or not, both allowing and denying need to be proven, at a minimum.