# How to read request custom header in aws s3 bucket policy security

Tags: security, amazon-s3

I am using cdn cache and adding custom header from cdn request. I want to check that custom header and allow request based on that to stop hotlinking.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Similar question: [Require a custom header on a get request for an s3 object in bucket policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43326170/174777)

Comment: in that case how to stop hotllining if if we need aws s3 objects calliing from andriod rest apis

Comment: Is there a back-end to your application that can handle authentication, or is all the logic in the mobile app itself?